# HTML typescript Comparing values in declaration Syntax

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript, ionic-framework

So right now I'm not sure of the syntax of comparing a value from TypeScript/JavaScript in HTML.

For example:

Typescript:

```
val1 = 0;
```

.HTML:

```
<ion-progress-bar class="my-bar" [color]="{{val1}} > 50 ? 'green' : 'red'"  value={{val1}} ></ion-progress-bar>
```

I read some HTML documentation that said to use greater than symbol you'd use `&gt;`, but this didn't work at all.

I want the color to be green if `val1 > 50` and red otherwise in HTML.

Comment: have you tried without the braces in the condition? like this [color]="val1 > 50 ? 'green' : 'red'"

Comment: This partially works! So it starts off red. Eventually val1 will be greater than 50. Trying to turn it green. It didn't update when val1 was greater than 50.

Comment: wait i did something wrong, testing again.

Comment: @bart it works 100% thank you so much!